# Getting self assigned ip 169.254.124.122 when connection to LAN with Huawei HG8145V

Tags: networking, router, dns, lan, macos-sierra

I am getting self assigned ip when connecting to Thunderbolt Display Ethernet using Thunderbolt Display. Connecting via WiFi works fine without any issues. I have tried setting up DNS in my macbook as well as in the router. But not getting the ip set via Router. Screenshot below:
[image]

[image]

With self assigned ip, I can't access the router login page. I have tried setting a default ip like 192.168.1.10 and then I am able to access the router, but still no connection with internet. Please advice what settings I need to change in order to access internet via LAN.

Comment: You have "DHCP relay" enabled, but where is it supposed to be relaying the requests?

Comment: If you're getting the APIPA (169.254.x.x) IP addresses, you're not communicating successfully with the DHCP server. If you've manually IP'd the system and still can't communicate, it maybe a defective adapter or incompatible with your network.

Comment: Check the cable - if any of the pins are not connecting, this can happen. Try the same setup with a different router.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try 2 approaches:

First manual config on the thunderbolt ethernet
IP 192.168.1.200
Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Router 192.168.1.1

If that doesn't work try disconnecting and deleting the thunderbolt network adapter, reboot, reconnect and it should aurodiscover and hopefully work.  If not manually add it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried both the approaches, it doesn't seem to work yet.

Comment: Check the cable - if any of the pins are not connecting, this can happen. Try the same setup with a different router.